# My wallet hasn't synchronized, can I make a transfer?

Tags: transactions, wallet, synchronization

My wallet hasn't synchronized, can I make a transfer?

I'm assuming that the transaction will not come up on my wallet but im guessing it would come up on the person I send too?

Comment: I tried to send btc while synchronizing. Nothing got sent during or after the synchronizing, but my wallet is down btc. Sits at 0/6 confirmations for hours with no action.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, making a transfer works pretty fine with the Bitcoin-Qt wallet.
However, the transfer won't be submitted to the network until your local client is up to date. Up to this point, the transaction is shown in your local wallet but not in the global network.

As an alternative you could use another wallet, for instance Electrum (http://electrum.org):
Electrum is a wallet that connects to servers that are already synchronized and thus will give you immediate results as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Bitcoin Core and have yet to synchronize  15 weeks of transactions with the network. Still I was able to send some bitcoins, and the transaction was registered on the blockchan immediately.

That is transaction has been submitted to the network. In was able to see it on https://blockchain.info.

However, the transaction resided in unconfirmed state until my client was fully synchronized with the network.

Answering to the question, yes it is possible to make a transfer, but it will not be confirmed until the sync is over. Check the status at blockchain.info.

Keep this in mind if you need the transfer to be processed fast.

Answer (score -1):

A solution would be to conduct an offline transaction which would be able to be submitted for confirmation immediately. There is a decent [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/4q6eal/i_want_to_sign_my_transaction_offline/) chatting about the process.

Comment: Please provide the relevant information in your answer and don't just link to another resource.